# Data Extraction from multiple Excel files and paste Using transpose and Link (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to Extract data from multiple Ranges in multiple Excel files, then transpose the copied data preserving the Link option. So under : `Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True` I added the following code : `ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True`

But using this code the macro doesn't correctly link the data. Thank you !

This is the code Im using :

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim FileNames As Variant

Dim i As Integer

Dim j As Integer
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("C2").Select
FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

For i = 1 To UBound(FileNames)
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Sheets("Global").Activate
    Range("D45:O45").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    'D45:O45 Line
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Sheets("Global").Activate
    Range("D8:O8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    'D8:O8 Line
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Sheets("Global").Activate
    Range("D24:O24").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    'D24:O24 Line
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Sheets("Global").Activate
    Range("D33:O33").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    'D33:O33 Line
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Sheets("Global").Activate
    Range("D5:O5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    'D5:O5 Line
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Sheets("Global").Activate
    Range("D38:O38").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    'D38:O38 Line
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Sheets("Global").Activate
    Range("D108:O108").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    'D108:O108 Line
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Sheets("Global").Activate
    Range("D10: O10 ").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    'D10:O10 Line
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Sheets("Global").Activate
    Range("D131:O131").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(12, -8).Activate
    'D131:O131 Line

Next i
                        
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the code in workbook `Dashboard.xlsm`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes it is

Comment: Then my posted solution should work.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you for your help.I have tested the Code it's exactly what I want there is just one thing about some empty cells that are generated between the imported data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `Paste Link` Workaround

- `Paste Link` does not work with `Transpose`.
- Assuming that the code is in the destination workbook and that the results will be written to its `ActiveSheet` (rather qualify with its name e.g. `"Sheet1"`), you can use the followng.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()

    ' Destination
    Const dstFirst As String = "C2"
    ' Source
    Const Cols As String = "D:O"
    Dim RowNumbers As Variant
    RowNumbers = VBA.Array(45, 8, 24, 33, 5, 38, 108, 10, 131)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet ' Better define: Set ws = wb.worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dstInit As Range
    Set dstInit = ws.Range(dstFirst)
    
    ' Source
    Dim DataCount As Long
    DataCount = ws.Columns(Cols).Count
    Dim LB As Long
    LB = LBound(RowNumbers)
    Dim UB As Long
    UB = UBound(RowNumbers)
    Dim FileNames As Variant
    FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
      FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", _
      Title:="Open File(s)", _
      MultiSelect:=True)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Prepare for loop.
    Dim src As Range      ' Current Source Range
    Dim dst As Range      ' Current Destination Range
    Dim i As Long         ' File Names Counter
    Dim j As Long         ' Destination Rows and Source Columns Counter
    Dim n As Long         ' Source Rows and Destination Columns Counter
    Dim CurForm As String ' Current Left Part of Formula
    
    ' Write values from Source to Destination.
    For i = 1 To UBound(FileNames)
        With Workbooks.Open(FileNames(i)).Worksheets("Global")
            CurForm = "='[" & .Parent.Name & "]" & .Name & "'!"
            Set dst = dstInit.Offset((i - 1) * DataCount)
            For n = LB To UB
                Set src = .Columns(Cols).Rows(RowNumbers(n))
                For j = 1 To DataCount
                    dst.Offset(j - 1, n).Formula _
                      = CurForm & src.Cells(j).Address(0, 0)
                Next j
            Next n
            .Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
                        
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked just Like magic. Thank you very much for your help you saved my day

Comment: But It's generating some kind of Empty Cells between the imported data based on files.

Comment: Do the empty cells contain formulas?

Comment: No they are empty I think It's something with the Offset maybe ?

Comment: You're right. I tested only on two workbooks. Will fix promptly.

Comment: Ah ok, Thank you very much for your help. PS : I have just noticed that the Empty Rows start to be generated after the gathered data from the Excel file number 3. Because there is no empty Rows between the 2 first datasets (Excel File 1 and Excel File 2)

Comment: I've fixed it. Sorry, my bad. The offset manipulation was wrong.